# How to Deploy React JS Application on Windows server with SSL certificate

Tags: reactjs, ssl, deployment

I want to deploy React JS application on windows Server with SSL.

What I have?

1. I have my own windows server.
2. I have my SSL certificate for [www.xyz.domain.com](http://www.xyz.domain.com)

I am not getting the proper flow for setting up SSL for ReactJS application.